# DrupalGap index.html No connection found on ios simulator

Tags: javascript

The app is working on web-app, but when I test iPhone" simulator, then have problems with connection:

index.html - No connection found

Failed connection 
http://app.newwweb.info
Check your device's network settings and try again.

I reviewed the changes in settings.js and index.html and are correct.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but solved it by including the plugin of network-information. Then both ios and android work fine.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`